# Cutting Dendrogram/Clustering Tree from SciPy at distance height

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm trying to learn how to use `dendrograms` in `Python` using `SciPy` . I want to get clusters and be able to visualize them; I heard `hierarchical clustering` and `dendrograms` are the best way.

**How can I "cut" the tree at a specific distance?**

In this example, I just want to cut it at distance `1.6`
[image]

I looked up a tutorial on https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/08/26/scipy-hierarchical-clustering-and-dendrogram-tutorial/#Inconsistency-Method but the guy did some really confusing wrapper function using `**kwargs` (he calls his threshold `max_d`)

Here is my code and plot below; I tried annotating it as best as I could for reproducibility:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram,linkage,fcluster
from scipy.spatial import distance
np.random.seed(424173239) #43984

#Dims
n,m = 20,7

#DataFrame: rows = Samples, cols = Attributes
attributes = ["a" + str(j) for j in range(m)]
DF_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((n, m)), columns = attributes)

A_dist = distance.cdist(DF_data.as_matrix().T, DF_data.as_matrix().T)

#(i) . Do the labels stay in place from DF_data for me to do this? 
DF_dist = pd.DataFrame(A_dist, index = attributes, columns = attributes)

#Create dendrogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Z = linkage(distance.squareform(DF_dist.as_matrix()), method="average")
D_dendro = dendrogram(Z, labels = attributes, ax=ax) #create dendrogram dictionary
threshold = 1.6 #for hline
ax.axhline(y=threshold, c='k')
plt.show()

#(ii) How can I "cut" the tree by giving it a distance threshold?
#i.e. If I cut at 1.6 it would make (a5 : cluster_1 or not in a cluster), (a2,a3 : cluster_2), (a0,a1 : cluster_3), and (a4,a6 : cluster_4)

#link_1 says use fcluster
#This -> fcluster(Z, t=1.5, criterion='inconsistent', depth=2, R=None, monocrit=None)
#gives me -> array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)

print(
     len(set(D_dendro["color_list"])), "^ # of colors from dendrogram",
     len(D_dendro["ivl"]), "^ # of labels",sep="\n")
#3 
#^ # of colors from dendrogram it should be 4 since clearly (a6, a4) and a5 are in different clusers
#7
#^ # of labels
```

link_1 : [How to compute cluster assignments from linkage/distance matrices in scipy in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951711/how-to-compute-cluster-assignments-from-linkage-distance-matrices-in-scipy-in-py)

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16883412/832621)...

Comment: @SaulloCastro thanks for that. Yea, it's definitely related.  An interesting way to only trees by going horizontally.  Also really cool to see how the actual graph is plotted too.

Answer (score 0):

`color_threshold` is the method I was looking for.  It doesn't really help when the `color_palette` is too small for the amount  of clusters being generated. Migrated the next step to [Bigger color-palette in matplotlib for SciPy's dendrogram (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538090/bigger-color-palette-in-matplotlib-for-scipys-dendrogram-python?noredirect=1#comment60681856_36538090) if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

For a bigger color palette this should work:

```
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy as hc
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as col

#get a color spectrum "gist_ncar" from matplotlib cm. 
#When you have a spectrum it begins with 0 and ends with 1. 
#make tinier steps if you need more than 10 colors

colors = cm.gist_ncar(np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)) 

colorlst=[]# empty list where you will put your colors
for i in range(len(colors)): #get for your color hex instead of rgb
    colorlst.append(col.to_hex(colors[i]))

hc.set_link_color_palette(colorlst) #sets the color to use.
```

Put all of that infront of your code and it should work